# adding value to prior row in dataframe within a function

Tags: python, function, pandas, vectorization

I am looking for a solution that produces column C (first row = 10000) within a function framework, i.e. without iterations but with vectorization:

```
index  A   B   c
 1     0   0   1000
 2     100 0    900
 3     0   0    900
 4     0  200  1100 
 5     0   0   1100
```

the Function should look similar to this:

```
 def calculate(self):
     df = pd.DataFrame()
     df['A'] = self.some_value
     df['B'] = self.some_other_value
     df['C'] = df['C'].shift(1) - df['A'] + df['B']........
```

but the reference to the prior row does not work. what can be done to accomplish the task lined out?

Comment: Why do you delete question? I have answer for you.

Comment: Or do you find answer too ? ;)

Comment: sorry, found a solution for the first part myself that made the question appear silly

Comment: No problem. ;) Another question is hard;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
df['C'] = 1000 + (-df['A'] + df['B']).cumsum()

df
Out[80]: 
     A    B     C
0    0    0  1000
1  100    0   900
2    0    0   900
3    0  200  1100
4    0    0  1100
```

Comment: still out of interest, is there a way to reference the prior cell (in the spirit of .shift(1)) in vectorized form? in the logic "if A= 100 then calculate C= 1000+A, else use prior cell Value of C"?

Comment: `.shift(1)` shifts an existing series, it is not a dynamic operation. What you describe is an iterative thing that would be very easy to do in Excel or with loops but for that operation you require processed version of the vector C (the previous value refers to the previous value that is being calculated with the same formula). However, pandas uses the existing vector with initial values. As far as I know, without loops what you describe is not possible.